# Mvc4 how can i use 2 tables in a single view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

This is an ASP.NET MVC4 project with Entity Framework.
I need to use 2 tables in single view

I have 2 tables in my database (Budgets and Products).

My **Models**

**Budget.cs**

```
public class Budget
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

**Product.cs**

```
  public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
    public int BudgetId { get; set; }
}
```

**BpDb**

```
 public class BpDb:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Budget> Budgets { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

**MasterBP**

```
 public class MasterBP
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<Product> ProdName { get; set; }
    public int CountOfValues { get; set; }
}
```

I need something about **Controller** to get ProdName (Title from table products)

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
{
    BpDb _db = new BpDb();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model=_db.Budgets
            .Select(r=>new MasterBP
            {
                Id = r.Id,
                Title = r.Title,
                ProdName = r.Products.Where(s => s.BudgetId == r.Id).ToList(), 
                CountOfValues = r.Products.Count()
            });
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

I need a way to get a list of products Title when the BudgetId = ID (1 Budget can have more than 1 Products)

And my **Index** is like:

`@model IEnumerable<MvcGg.Models.MasterBP>`

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
  {
      <div>
          <h4>@item.Title</h4>
          @foreach (var product in item.ProdName)
          {
              @(product.Title.ToString());
          }
          Values:@item.CountOfValues
      </div>
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like (correct me if I am wrong) you want to access two sets of entities in your view model?

Then something along these lines will do:

```
public class BudgetsViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<MasterBP> MasterBps { get;set; }
    public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get;set;}
}
```

And then you just retrieve all the data and populate the viewmodel and pass it down.

```
...
var budgets =_db.Budgets
            .Select(r=>new MasterBP
            {
                Id = r.Id,
                Title = r.Title,
                ProdName = r.Products.Where(s => s.BudgetId == r.Id).ToList(), 
                CountOfValues = r.Products.Count()
            });
var model = new BudgetsViewModel()
{
   MasterBps = budgets
   //Products here
}

return View(model);
...
```

However it would be better if you made some form of service layer to handle the retrieving on entities and the mapping to view models instead of having all this logic in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

finally this solve my problem,

**Model**:

**MasterBP**

```
public class MasterBP
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Product> ProdName { get; set; }
    public int CountOfValues { get; set; }
}
```

I replaced `List<>` with `IEnumerable<>`

**Controller**:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model=_db.Budgets
            .Select(r=>new MasterBP
            {
                Id = r.Id,
                Title = r.Title,
                ProdName = r.Products.Where(s => s.BudgetId == r.Id).AsEnumerable(),
                CountOfValues = r.Products.Count()
            });    

        return View(model);
    }
```

In addition i have change `ToList()` in `AsEnumerable()` and now i can see my result using this

**View**:

**Index**

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div>
        @item.Title
        <ul>
            @foreach (var prod in item.ProdName)
            {

                <li>@prod.Title</li>

            }
        </ul>
        <hr />
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Did you not see my answer? Or try it?

Comment: Can you please accept it then to help other members who come across this question

Comment: @Glitch100 ok, but i couldn't use it  because i don't know how to call it correct in my index ( I am new here).

Comment: You would make a new class, a ProductsService or something like that, and have a method return the data from your context (like you are already) and then iterate over that to make the new model I provided. Have a look at Repository/Service Layer stuff on google or here:)